# Strongly typed solution for "types" of Points

Tags: c++

I am trying to represent points in two "types of space": Window space and world space. I have a 2d vector class which is the raw data.

What is the best way to "strongly type" these two without re-writing my 2d vector class? Ie i would have to re-write all the operator+= operator-, operator+ and so forth.

My current code for the two points is below. I'm looking for a "better solution". I define better as strong typing, and able to write code like this:

```
pos += {0, -1};
```

Without having to write a full suite of operators for WindowPosition and WorldPosition.

My current solution:

```
struct WindowPosition
{
  template<typename... Args>
  WindowPosition(Args&&... args)
    : m_coords(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
  {}

  operator math::v2&() { return m_coords; }
  operator const math::v2&() const { return m_coords; };

  math::v2 m_coords;
};


struct WorldPosition
{
    template<typename... Args>
    WorldPosition(Args&&... args)
      : m_coords(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {}

    operator math::v2&() { return m_coords; }
    operator const math::v2&() const { return m_coords; };

    WindowPosition ToWindowPosition()
    {
      return globals::CAMERA->ToWindowRelative(m_coords);
    }

    math::v2 m_coords;
};
```

But this means I have to do this instead: pos.m_coords += {0, -1};

Is there a better way to achieve what I've described above? Or is there a more idiomatic solution?

****EDIT: here is what I ended up going with. Thanks @jzwinck:

```
struct Window {};
struct World {};

template <typename Tag>
struct Position : math::v2
{
  template<typename... Args>
  Position(Args&&... args)
    : math::v2(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
  {}
};

typedef Position<Window> WindowPosition;
typedef Position<World> WorldPosition;

WindowPosition ToWindowPosition(const WorldPosition& pos)
{
  return globals::CAMERA->ToWindowRelative(pos);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templates!

```
struct Window {};
struct World {};

template <typename Tag>
struct Position
{
  template<typename... Args>
  Position(Args&&... args)
    : m_coords(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
  {}

  operator math::v2&() { return m_coords; }
  operator const math::v2&() const { return m_coords; };

  math::v2 m_coords;
};

typedef Position<Window> WindowPosition;
typedef Position<World> WorldPosition;

WindowPosition ToWindowPosition(const WorldPosition& pos)
{
  return globals::CAMERA->ToWindowRelative(pos);
}
```

Comment: I implemented this *exact* same thing in code, but I still can't do operator += {0, 1} etc:( I think there is no way around that part of it without writing a full suite of operators.

Comment: @tmruss: What if you tweak it by making `math::v2` a public base class of `Position` instead of aggregating and exposing it as a member?

Comment: I also went away from templates because I wanted to hide ToWindowPosition's implementation in a cpp file eventually. The standalone function method is also an option but it feels harder to use than the member func.

Comment: @tmruss: The free function approach is superior in this case.

Comment: @jzwinck I tried that too - I wasn't 100% sure how i'd avoid implicit conversion issues between multiple things that "are" a vector. I think i'd need to delete the constructor which allows construction from a math::v2.. or something.

Comment: @tmruss are you sure C++ support syntax like `pos += {0, -1};`?

Comment: @jzwinck and another question... would you think it odd if you saw some code inheriting from a math::v2 :)?

Comment: @MarsonMao absolutely - I'm using vs2013 though. I didn't post the implementation of math::v2 but up until trying to strongly type these things i've had no problems with the braced syntax.

Comment: @tmruss Though you're not asking me, but I think according to the is-a relationship of your `Window/World Position` and `math::v2`, I think let them inherit from `math:v2` is good.

Comment: @MarsonMao Thanks for the feedback. I ended up going that approach. Really appreciate it!